# Malware is changing my <title> and <description> tags and I can't find the issue

Tags: wordpress

When I go to my site, the title and description tags are fine. They are identified properly. I have viewed the source in chrome, firefox, and safari.

When I go to the facebook developers site and troubleshoot the metadata, and I "scrape again" and "scrape again" and "scrape again," it is dynamically populating pharmaceutical products into the title and descriptions.

I have updated the theme to the most recent version, and I have already updated wordpress to 5.5.3.

How do I remove the malware that is dynamically flipping these entries when Facebook or Twitter are pulling the metadata??

Here is an example: https://www.modeluneducation.com/what-we-teach/
When you go to the facebook developers site, the data is different, even though it was scraped 10 minutes ago.

Comment: Try scanning your wordpress installation with the Wordfence plugin

Comment: This seems to have worked